# Is a transit visa necessary for UK?

Tags: visas, uk, transit, jamaican-citizens

A friend from Jamaica is visiting me in Nigeria. He has a valid US visa. His return flight is from Lagos to London Heathrow, and then London Gatwick to Kingston, all on British Airways. He will be transiting within six hours.

Does he need a transit visa for this?

Comment: It's not a duplicate if the 'original' answer is wrong.